# Too much memory usage of IIS application pool

Tags: iis

My Windows Server is running an web application on IIS 7.5.

I'm wondering why IIS application pools use a lot of memory.

Please refer to the screenshop I captured from the servere.

[image]

In the application pool named TEST 2.0 (.NET Framework Version 2.0), there is only one small web service. However, it takes about 3GB for Virtual Bytes.

Also, in the application pool named TEST 4.0 (.NET Framework Version 4.0), there is only one web service doing nothing. However, it allocates about 9GB for Virtual Bytes.

Do you know why IIS 7.5 occupies huge memory? What's the problem?

Do you have any intuitive ideas about it?

To give you more ideas, here is my system environment:

- OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard SP1
- HW: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5670 @ 2.93GHz 2.93GHz / 8.0GB RAM

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Nothing is wrong :)

You are not actually using 2GB of RAM. That is merely the allowed address space for this process. **Private Bytes** is the measure of RAM usage (so, 90MB in this case).

From the PerfMon definition for Virtual Bytes:

**Virtual Bytes** - Virtual Bytes is the current size, in bytes, of the virtual address space the process is using. Use of virtual address space does not necessarily imply corresponding use of either disk or main memory pages. Virtual space is finite, and the process can limit its ability to load libraries.

Comment: Thanks RB., but do you know why each application pool allocates a lot of Virtual Bytes in advance? When you see TEST 2.0 and TEST 4.0 application pool in my screenshot, the number after 'TEST' stands for .NET Framework Version. As you see, TEST 4.0 occupies four times more than TEST 2.0. Can you explain about this?

Comment: The current problem is that IIS randomly generates the error: Server Error in '/OECDStatWCF_OData' Application.
Memory gates checking failed because the free memory (373817344 bytes) is less than 5% of total memory.  As a result, the service will not be available for incoming requests.  To resolve this, either reduce the load on the machine or adjust the value of minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService on the serviceHostingEnvironment config element.